# Передача картинок в компонент через пропсы в React.js

Tags: reactjs, jsx

Я только-только начинаю изучать React.js и его подходы как таковые, поэтому если кто-то посчитает вопрос глупым и прочее - не судите строго. Я верстаю сайт, где на главной странице у меня отображается перечень услуг - компонент `<ServiceList />`, состоящий, в свою очередь, из компонентов `<ServiceItem />`. Вот мой шаблон компонента `<ServiceItem />`:

```
const ServiceItem = (props) => {
return (
        <div>

            // Желаемая картинка, которая чхать хотела на пропсы
            <img src={props.service.img}>

            // Описание услуги, которое замечательно подтягивается пропсами
            <span>{props.service.title}</span>

        </div>
    );
}
```

Сам компонент я в дальнейшем импортирую в `ServiceList` компонент, где по задумке с помощью массива объектов будет отображаться столько компонентов `ServiceItem`, сколько мне нужно, используя пропсы, которые мне нужны. Вот так выглядит компонент `<ServiceList />`:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import ServicesItem from './ServiceItem';

const ServicesList = () => {
    const [services] = useState ([
        {id: 1, img: '../../../src/img/santech/Смеситель on.png', title: 'Установка смесителя',},
        {id: 2, title: 'Проверка счетчиков',},
        {id: 3, title: 'Магнитный ключ',},
        и так далее.....
    ])

    return ( 
        <div>

            {services.map(service => 
                <ServicesItem
                    service={service}
                    key={service.id}
                />
            )}

        </div>
    );
}
```

Так вот, с заголовками услуг ( props.service.title ) проблем нет, всё динамически подтягивается как надо, а вот с картинками иллюстрациями ( props.service.img ) я намучался уже. Картинки мои хранятся в файле проекта, в пути `../../../src/img/santech/...` и компонент их видеть не видит

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я почитал пару статей и пару похожих вопросов на форумах и понял, что вроде как, то что я хочу сделать вообще не реализуемо. Что если заголовок строкой может передаться через пропсы, то url до картинки то же текстом через пропсы передаться не может. Я пробовал и через инлайновый стиль `BackgroundImage`, и пробовал пути менять на абсолютные (`http://localhost/.....`).

Вероятнее всего, я просто делаю *"по-джуниорски"* и то, что я хочу передать url картинки через хук useState() - делать не стоит. Опытные разработчики, подскажите новичку в реакте, реализуема ли передача урла картинки через данных хук? Задумка такая, что я в одном месте, в том самом массиве объектов, при желании мог бы поменять заголовок любой услуги на другой, и любую картинку услуги на другую. По этому, желательно, не отходить далеко от идеи импортов пропсов через массив объектов.

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Ну во первых, вижу пробел в названии, что уже может вызывать проблемы пути. Во вторых, вы указываете локальный путь для дев билда, т.е. на самом деле у вас в скомпилированном варианте путь до картинки будет другой. Можно сделать подключение картинок из например папки assets через вебпак конфиг (если используется этот сборщик), либо оно может быть из коробки в другом сборщике. Также можно подключить CopyWebpackPlugin и он будет автоматически подтягивать все картинки из указанной папки, а в src можно будет вставить что то вроде "images/somePic.jpg"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

как все это происходит:

когда ты запускаешь скрипт запуска (npm start или yarn start или ...) весь код который ты написал компилируется в js/css и кладется в какую то папку (название папок в основном build или dist или .next) и там же есть index.html на основе которого ты и видишь в браузере результат, так вот после компиляции(этим занимается например webpack) имена файлов меняются(на это есть своя причина), так вот после сборки нету никакого `../../../src/img/santech/Смеситель on.png`, нету не таких папок, не такого файла, соответственно это некорректный путь. Все это можно увидеть если запустить скрипт сборки(в основном имя скрипта build) вместо разработки (скрипты в package.json), после запуска появится папка в которой ты и увидишь весь скомпилированный код.

есть два варианта, если это не удаленный ресурс( `https://....` )

1:

```
import someImgSrc from 'путь/img.формат' (`../../some-img.png`)

    const Comp = () => { 
     return <img src={someImgSrc}/> 
    }
```

2: через сборщик типа webpack, скопировать папку где лежат картинки в конечную папку после сборки (название папок в основном build или dist или .next)

например в create-react-app или в vite все что в папке public копируется в финальную папку сборки, то есть можно что то положить туда и использовать в коде в любом месте так:

```
<img src='/my-img.png'/>
```

юзать можно так

Comment: благодарю, правда про Webpack не особо понял. Знаю, что он в create-react-app используется как сборщик по умолчанию, но что он из себя представляет и как работать с папками после сборки ещё не довелось узнать

Comment: @Александр, В cra он настроен уже и скрыт, для модификации конфигурации webpack надо либо запустить скрипт eject, либо установить через npm craco и уже в настройках craco что-то добавлять.

Answer (score 0):

Сделай импорты картинок:

```
import { magnetKey } from '../../src/Магнитный ключ.jpg'
```

А дальше передавай ее внутрь:

```
const ServicesList = () => {
    const [services] = useState ([
        {id: 1, src={magnetKey}, title: 'Установка смесителя',},
        {id: 2, title: 'Проверка счетчиков',},
        {id: 3, title: 'Магнитный ключ',},
        и так далее.....
    ])
```

При такой передаче путей сборщик учтет добавленный хэш к имени файла